# Combine n lists of length y into y lists of length n

Tags: python

If I have:

```
>>> a=[1,2]
>>> b=[3,4]
>>> c=[5,6]
```

Is there a one-liner to get:

```
d = ([1,3,5],[2,4,6])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
d = zip(a, b, c)
```

up to tuple/list differences.

Comment: Great, thanks. I was trying `zip((a,b,c))` which was giving me something else.

Comment: if you have a tuple of the lists, i.e. `(a, b, c)`, you can pass it to `zip` like so: `d = zip(*(a, b, c))`.  This unpacks the tuple `(a, b, c)` to pass them as arguments to `zip`.

For python 3.x, zip provides a generator, and you should use `d = tuple(zip(a, b, c))` to get `d = ([1,3,5],[2,4,6])`.